# How can I get max of each row within an index column

Tags: pandas

My dataframe is a multi index data frame for columns, I would like to have maximum for level 1 for each row, something like this.

```
        max_values = pivot_df.max(axis=0, level=1)
```

For example:

```
A     B 
c  d  e   f
2  4  3   2
4  1  2   6
```

Request:

```
A   B
4   3
4   6
```

Comment: Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` first then `max`:

```
max_values = pivot_df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).max()
print(max_values)

# Output
   A  B
0  4  3
1  4  6
```

Comment: @Ahmad. I updated my answer now that you updated your post with a MWE.